# Como executar widgets que utilizam o QTimer a partir de uma Thread diferente?

Tags: python, python-3.x, thread, pyqt-5

Criei uma aplicação onde o usuário pressiona uma determinada combinação de teclas — utilizando o pacote `pynput` — e uma mensagem vinda de um "[QToaster](https://github.com/JeanExtreme002/Virtual-Assistant/blob/new_version/src/gui/toaster.py)" aparece na tela. Abaixo está um código de exemplo:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from toaster import show_message         # Toaster criado a partir de um QFrame com QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

def func():
    show_message("Executado com sucesso.")

app = QApplication([])
thread = keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({"<ctrl>+<alt>+z": func})
thread.start()
app.exec_()
```

O problema é que sempre que eu executo o código e pressiono as teclas, o `QToaster` trava e a seguinte mensagem de erro é impressa no console:

```
QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread
```

Eu sei que esse erro está sendo gerado porque o QToaster não é criado na *main thread*. A minha dúvida é: como executar o `QToaster` a partir de uma outra Thread sem que ele trave, a partir de um sinal ou algo parecido? Em PyQt5 existe algum recurso que me permita executar um código de uma Thread diferente a partir de um sinal, como no código abaixo?

```
executor = Executor()
executor.set_function(lambda: show_message("Executado com sucesso."))

thread = keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({"<ctrl>+<alt>+z": executor.start})
thread.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu sinceramente não sei se essa é a melhor solução para este problema, mas ainda assim é uma solução. Sim, existe um recurso no PyQt5 para criar sinais e é a classe [`QtCore.pyqtSignal`](https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html).

Através dela, você pode definir uma função a ser executada — utilizando o método `connect` — e passar para a thread o método `emit` que, ao ser executado, irá emitir um sinal para executar a função que você conectou.

O problema é que para utilizar o `pyqtSignal`, você deve seguir algumas regras:

1. Você só poderá utilizá-lo dentro de uma classe que herda de `QCore.QObject`.
2. O objeto de `pyqtSignal` deve ser criado como um atributo da classe.

Dito isso, o seu código ficaria assim:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from toaster import show_message  
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys

def func():
    show_message("Executado com sucesso.")

class MyClass(QObject):   # Não estou tão criativo hoje para dar nome de classe, sorry ;)
    signal = pyqtSignal()

app = QApplication([])

myObject = MyClass()
myObject.signal.connect(func)

thread = keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({"<ctrl>+<alt>+z": myObject.signal.emit})
thread.start()
app.exec_()
```